# How to plot a Percentage graph in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Suppose I have a data like

```
 df = pd.Dataframe({'id': [1,2,3,4,5], 'Disease' : [0,0,1,0,1], 'code':['A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A']})
```

Now I know that if I groupby code

```
m = df.groupby(df.code).size()
```

I have the frequency chart of people with code A and B. I need to plot this as a bar graph but I want the percentage graph. That is y axis is percentage from 0 to 100 and x-axis to be code. I want see what percent of people with code A has status 0 and 1, similarly the other way round. As someone dealt with this before ?

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
df.groupby('code').mean()['Disease'].plot(kind='bar')
```

It will be a fraction, not percentage, but I'm sure you can take it form here.

Comment: this is a more elegant version:
df['Disease'].groupby(df.code).mean().plot(kind='bar')

Comment: I want stacked in this with showing status 0 and 1 in different colors

Comment: Use the 'color' variable of DataFrame.plot , like this:
df['Disease'].groupby(df.code).mean().plot(kind='bar', color=['red', 'green'])